# Unable to use Filter macros across all worksheets due to different table names assigned by Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

Looking to create a filter on column D to have "NO" and column E "blanks". I have done these by recording a macro as shown below. However, I am unable to create a macros button and apply across all worksheets as excel assigns different table names to each worksheets.

For instance the one below has been assigned **Table6814151416171924282737404145498914**. Anyway of going around this so that I can have one button that can be applied across worksheets?

```
Sub yet2attend()
'
' yet2attend Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("**Table6814151416171924282737404145498914**").Range. _
        AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="NO"
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("**Table6814151416171924282737404145498914**").Range. _
        AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="="

End Sub
```

If I can get around this, I will then create a macros button to reset/remove filters. Thanks

[screenshot of table from column A to I](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxN1G.png)

Comment: Have a look here https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/clear-filters-showalldata/ it will show you how to deal with normal sheet filters as well as filters that is part of an Excel table. Excel tables are stores in ListObjects, like you seem to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there more than one table per worksheet?
Each table is stored as a ListObject object, and you can use the `ListObjects` property of the Worksheet object, to point to your table, which is also what you are doing in your code.
So you can loop through the worksheets, and apply the filter for each table. And if there's only one table per sheet, it's easy to use the `index` rather than the name,  since it'll always be the first table on the sheet.

```vb
Sub yet2attend()
Dim tbl As ListObject, sht As Worksheet
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    sht.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="NO"
    sht.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="="
Next sht
End Sub
```

Or, if the button is per sheet, and only supposed to filter the sheet you are on, you can use what you have and just change the name to index.

```vb
Sub yet2attend()
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="NO"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="="
End Sub
```

If you have multiple tables per sheet, and you want a universal approach, they need to have something in common.
If you can't make sure they have the same index, but they all are in the same range, you can use that to tell excel which table you want to filter.

By using the `Intersect` method, we can check if something occupies a specific range. And the `ListObjects.Range` property returns the range of the table.
`Intersect(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range, Range("A1")` will return the range where the two ranges intersect, if any. We aren't interested in knowing WHERE, but IF.
If the ranges do not intersect, `Intersect` will return `nothing`. Knowing this, we can loop through the tables of the sheet, and only affect the one that isn't returning nothing – hence in our range.

```vb
Sub yet2attend()
Dim tbl As ListObject
For Each tbl In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
    If Not Intersect(tbl.Range, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="NO"
        tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="="
    End If
Next tbl
End Sub
```

Comment: This works! Thanks! I know I am asking too much but I am struggling to undo all filters/reset filters using macro. Tens of options found online not working. Any idea?

Comment: Should work to just remove the criteria `ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=4` should clear "D".

Comment: Spent days on this. That too worked! Thank you very very much